# Show 3 div one by one depending on input filed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a search form. Here when a user clicks on input filed first show a div (id: 1) where will be some link, then when user type on the input filed first for search div (id: 1) will hide and second div (id: 2) will show that place. Here will show the search result. After that, select a search result, the third div (id: 3) will appear here. In this process, if the user clicks outside on the window div will hide.
For reference please visit this site and see the search form. https://www.immobiliare.it/

Here is my code:

```
<div id="1">
    <button>Open Map in Modal</button>
    <button>Open Map in Modal 2</button>
</div>
<div id="2">
    <p>Search result</p>
    <p>Search result</p>
    <!-- this will fetch result via AJAX, try with static data for testing. just show the div -->
</div>
<div id="3">
    <input type="checkbox"> Villa
    <input type="checkbox"> Apartment
    <input type="checkbox"> Cotage
</div>
```

```
<style>

#1{
    display: none;
}
#2{
    display: none;
}
#3{
    display: none;
}

.form-group input::focus + #1{
    display: block;
}
```

```
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('searchLocation');
 var result = document.getElementById('2');
    input.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
    result.style.display = "block";
      });
    input.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
     result.style.display = "none";
      });
</script>
```

I tried with focus in-out method. But the problem is I can't click on the div content, because of focus out, the div hide.

Please see the referecnce link, I want to make similiar. I just need the design only.

Comment: Looking at the CSS, where is the class "form-group" in your HTML code?  You're using a sibling selector and that requires it to be tag immediately preceding the tag with the ID of "1".  Also, small note:  CSS IDs normally can't start with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!-- <form> -->
        <input type="search" placeholder=" Search..." id="searchbox" name="searchitem" list="searchhints">
    <!-- </form> -->
    <datalist id="searchhints"> 
    <!--        <option>Open Map in Modal 1</option>
        <option>Open Map in Modal 2</option> -->
    </datalist>
    <div id="display">
        <input type="checkbox"> Villa
        <input type="checkbox"> Apartment
        <input type="checkbox"> Cottage
    </div>
```

```
<script>
    var default_datalist = {"Open Map in Modal 1" : "modal1", "Open Map in Modal 2" : "modal2"};
    var searched_datalist = {"Search result 1": "search1", "Search result 2": "search2"};
    $(function(){
        $("#display").hide();
        fill_searchhints(default_datalist);
    })


    function fill_searchhints(datalist) {
        $("#searchhints").html("");
        for (let data in datalist) {
            $("#searchhints").append("<option><div id='"+datalist[data]+"'>"+data+"</div></option");
        }
    }


    $("body").delegate("#searchbox","change input",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($("#searchbox").val()!=''){
            keyword = $('#searchbox').val();
            //send keyword to AJAX function
            fill_searchhints(searched_datalist);

            if(keyword == 'Search result 1'){
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#display").show();
            }
            
        } else {
            fill_searchhints(default_datalist);
        }
    });
</script>
```

You can do something along this line. Here I have used `datalist` tag instead instead of div. In script, i have created `default_datalist` and `searched_datalist` to replace `datalist` in HTML. Rest are normal functions, loops and event-listeners.

The link you provided seems to mainly use AJAX with backend search as well, so it is kinda difficult to replicate same result in here

**Edit**:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" name="search" id="search">
<div id="div1" class="drop" hidden>
    <button>Open Map in Modal</button>
    <button>Open Map in Modal 2</button>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="drop" hidden>
    <p>Search result</p>
    <p>Search result</p>
</div>
<div id="div3" hidden>
    <input type="checkbox"> Villa
    <input type="checkbox"> Apartment
    <input type="checkbox"> Cottage
</div>
<script>
    $("#search").on("focusin input change", function(){
        $(".drop").hide();
        if($("#search").val() == ""){
            $("#div1").show();
              //    $("#div3").hide();
        } else {
            $("#div2").show();
        }
    })

    $("#search").on("focusout", function() {
        $(".drop").hide();
    })

    $("#div2").on("mousedown", function(){
        $("#div3").show();
    });
</script>
```

Here, if you apply the commented part, #div3 will hide when input text is empty,

Comment: I just need the design with static data. Just complete those three steps.

Comment: There isn't any sort of design needed here. You just need to use datalist instead of first and second div. The elements inside these elements are populated using AJAX

Comment: first div is fixed. second and third div will be dynamical. I understand. Can you please help me with the first div at least? When click on the input filed first div will show. And when click on the outside of the div it will close.

Comment: I found a little workaround using `mousedown` event, do check it out. I don't think i can do any more in here